# Fairly minor bug on Stack Overflow edit profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, merge-accounts, profile-page

When trying to save my profile on Stack Overflow, and the email is already taken, this is what happens:

[image]

The `account recovery page` bit is not linked, and the HTML code for the link is displayed. Yes, it's very minor, but I think that it's still worth noting, and possibly fixing.

Answer (score 8):

It is always better (even if it is a little uglier) to accidentally over-encode than to under-encode. This has been fixed locally, and should percolate through to the site soon (edit: now deployed)

Comment: Nice! But what happened to the OP here??

Comment: I get he recovered his account. `:)`