# Bug faced during updating my account information

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fairly minor bug on Stack Overflow edit profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164108/fairly-minor-bug-on-stack-overflow-edit-profile-page)

I was updating my account information (e.g., my another email, name e.t.c.,). when I clicked on save button I got the below error

```
Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
•This email address is already registered. 
 If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our 
 <a href="/users/account-recovery">account recovery page</a> 
 to get access to this account.
```

As you can see that there is an anchor tag here, so there was no link appeared but an anchor tag appeared. I request you to make it appear like proper HTML link.

Comment: Do you mean it showed up as clear text? I edited to show that more clearly, feel free to roll back if that's not what you meant

Comment: yes its minor but still its worth taking attention. btu anyway i am happy for your quick response.